# Dispersion parameter for Gamma family

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I have ran a glm in R, and near the bottom of the summary() output, it states:

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 1.680014)

What does this mean/represent?

Comment: Do you mean what implications it has for your scientific question or do you concerned about what it means fr the gamma distribution?

Answer (score 19):

Gamma distribution defined by two parameters - shape ($\alpha$) and rate ($\beta$).

There is alternative parameterization through mean ($\mu$) and shape, which is used in GLM.

We take $\mu = \alpha/\beta$ and put it into place of rate (as $\beta = \alpha/\mu$), resulting in function $Gamma(\mu,\alpha)$.

In R GLM assumes shape to be a constant (as linear regression assumes constant variance). To satisfy this assumption dispersion ($\phi$) is introduced:
$$
\phi = \frac{1}{\alpha}
$$

For the simple case `glm(x ~ 1, family = Gamma(link = 'identity))`, `summary.glm` gives you $\text{estimate}$, that is equal to $\mu$ (note that default link is 'inverse' and estimate = $1/\mu$) and $\text{dispersion}$ is $\phi$.

Comment: Does μ changes for different value of explanatory variables?

Comment: @tatami Well, in my example $\mu$ is the mean of `x`. But in general effects estimates of explanatory variables would change in accordance with model.