# Help understanding parameterization of gamma distribution in R's glm()

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution

I would like recover the gamma distribution parameters from a model fit in R using `glm(..., family = Gamma)`. The first step is trying to figure out which parameterization R's `glm` function uses for the gamma distribution. Looking through `?glm`, `?family`, and `?Gamma` didn't help me. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/247631/45889) was helpful in understanding the parameterization, but doesn't say much  about recovering the parameter estimates from the output. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/367563/45889) explains how to get the dispersion estimate from the fit model object, and I use that and the estimated mean values to calculate the [shape and scale parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

```
# model from example in ?glm
clotting <- data.frame(
  u = c(5,10,15,20,30,40,60,80,100),
  lot1 = c(118,58,42,35,27,25,21,19,18),
  lot2 = c(69,35,26,21,18,16,13,12,12))
fit <- glm(lot1 ~ log(u), data = clotting, family = Gamma)


# mean = shape * scale (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)
# mean can be directly obtained from model output
mu <- fit$fitted.values
# mu <- predict(fit, type = 'response')

# dispersion = residual deviance / residual degrees of freedom (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/367563/45889)
dispersion <- (fit$deviance / fit$df.residual)
# and shape parameter is inverse of dispersion (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/247631/45889)
shape <- 1 / dispersion
# scale = mu / shape (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)
scale <- mu / shape

# variance = shape * scale^2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)
var <- shape * scale^2
```

Is this correct? Because when I try to manually calculate Pearson residuals, my Pearson residuals differ from R's Pearson residuals by a factor of `sqrt(shape)`.

```
# raw residuals
observed <- clotting$lot1
expected <- fit$fitted.values
raw_residuals <- observed - expected

# Pearson residuals = raw residuals / variance function (https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/insight/chap39/sect56.htm)
pearson_residuals <- raw_residuals / sqrt(var)

# but when I compare this to R's Pearson residuals, they're different
all.equal(resid(fit, 'pearson'), pearson_residuals)

# they're different by a factor of sqrt(shape)
pearson_residuals / resid(fit, 'pearson')
sqrt(shape)

var2 <- var * shape
pearson_residuals2 <- raw_residuals / sqrt(var2)
all.equal(resid(fit, 'pearson'), pearson_residuals2)
# TRUE
```

What am I missing? I have been assuming that I'm misunderstanding something with the parameterization of the gamma distribution, but perhaps am I doing something wrong with the Pearson residuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pearson residuals rescale using the variance function $V(\mu)$ but not using the estimated dispersion parameter. So if $\mathrm{var}[Y]=\sigma^2V(\mu)$,
$$r_P = \frac{y-\mu}{\sqrt{V(\mu)}}$$
not
$$r_P = \frac{y-\mu}{\hat\sigma\sqrt{V(\mu)}}$$

Obviously it doesn't matter for most graphical purposes whether the scale factor of $\hat\sigma$ is in there or not; it was at one point a free choice.  The implementation in R followed that in S, which followed people who defined Pearson residuals without the $\hat\sigma$ term.

It's convenient to leave it out for a few reasons. First, you can define $\hat\sigma^2$ as just the variance of the Pearson residuals.  Second, for linear/Gaussian glms you end up with the Pearson residuals being the same as the raw residuals (and the working residuals and the deviance residuals).

Comment: And since the variance function of the gamma distribution is `mu^2`, I divide the raw residuals by `mu` to get the Pearson residuals.